# How can I compare the current selection with the clipboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to compare the current selected text with the text of the clipboard?

I only found this (ctrl-shift-p: "compare"):

> Compare active file with clipboard

Answer (score 2):

If you are a VS Code user, you can use the [`ryu1kn.partial-diff`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff) extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

Or you could create a new untitled file, paste the contents, and then use the `File: Compare Active File with Clipboard` command in the command palette, or its associated keyboard shortcut.

Read on if you are an extension developer.

To get the currently selected text in the active editor, use `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection`. ([Docs for `TextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor)).

To get the system clipboard contents, just use `env.clipboard`.

- [Docs for `env`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#env)
- [Docs for `Clipboard`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Clipboard)

The `readText` method of `Clipboard`'s docs:

> Read the current clipboard contents as text.

Its return type: `Thenable<string>`. ([Docs for `Thenable`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Thenable)).

And then just use regular string comparison functions / operators such as `===`.

Comment: I am a use of vscode, not a plugin developer. But I found the PartialDiff plugin, which can compare to the selected lines to the content of the clipboard. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff